# PHP: passing array elements into class function in fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Working on a project and need to generate pdf of the product details using FPDF. The product details are passed into an array and I need the following to get each of the variable elements in the array '$prod_details' into the functions within the class 'PDF' as shown below:

Examples of how I tried passing the variable array elements:

```
    $this->Cell(30,8,$prod_data['prod_name'],0,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(30,10,$prod_data['company_name']);
    $this->Cell(20,8,$prod_data['prod_cost'],0,0,'C');
```

I have tried running this script but I keep getting an error message 'Cannot access empty property'...

find the codes below

```
<?php

@include_once("includes/db.php");
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
@include_once("includes/class_product_info.php");

$obj = new allProducts();
$prod_data = array();
if(isset($_GET['c_id'])){
        $prod_data = $obj->getProdDetails($_GET['c_id']);

class PDF extends FPDF
{   


public $prod_data;

public function createData($input){
    $this->prod_data = $input;
}

function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('big_logo.png',10,6,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',20);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(40);    
    // Title
    $this->Cell(30,10,$this->prod_data['company_name']);
    // Draw an header line
    $this->Line(10,26,200,26);
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);

    // Begin with regular font
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    // Then put a blue underlined link
    //$this->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
    $this->SetFont('','U');
    $this->Write(10,$this->prod_data['company_name'],'http://www.skills.com');
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',9);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().' ',0,0,'R');
}

function prodDetailTop()
{
// Course title cell
$this->Cell('',10,'',0,0,'C');
$this->Ln();

/* Build cells for the first row */

$this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$this->SetY(40);

// First Row
$this->Cell(35,8,'Product Name : ',0,0,'L');
$this->Cell(30,8,$this->prod_data['prod_name'],0,0,'C');
$this->SetX(150);
$this->Cell(25,8,'Product Cost : ',0,0,'L');
$this->Cell(20,8,$this->prod_data['prod_cost'],0,0,'C');
$this->Ln();

// Second Row
$this->Cell(35,8,'Discount : ',0,0,'L');
$this->Cell(30,8,$this->prod_data['disc_amt'],0,0,'L');
$this->SetX(150);
$this->Cell(25,8,'No Purchased : ',0,0,'L');
$this->Cell(20,8,$this->prod_data['items_count'].' product(s)',0,0,'L');
$this->Ln();
}


function prodDetailBtm()
{

$this->SetY(80);

$this->Write(10,$this->prod_data['prod_desc']);

}

function generatePageData()
{
    $this->AddPage();
    $this->prodDetailTop();
    $this->prodDetailBtm();
}
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->createData($prod_data);
//$pdf->Header();

$pdf->generatePageData();
$pdf->Output();

}
else {

?>
    <script language="javascript">
    window.location = "prod_invoice_err.php";
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Hope to get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague. It would be helpful it you asked specifically what you're trying to accomplish.

But the first thing I see is that your subclass of the fpdf class, you don't need to write functions to do each and everything you want to do with the pdf. You only need to extend the parts of the class you are overriding (or extending), like header and footer.

So extend it, manipulate header and footer, then close the class. Create your $pdf instance of your new fpdf class, then manipulate that object with your data. You don't need to 'pass in' that data at all.

for instance:

```
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->Cell($w,9,$title,1,1,'C',true); //from fpdf tutorial
```

Or, if that doesn't accomplish what you want (although I can't see why it wouldn't, I've done this lots of times), you can always override the constructor. Pass in an array (or event a custom object that you create), and store that in a private variable.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to help. I have re-edited the question and it's more specific now. I hope you understand the challenge I'm going through with the codes after reading through it again.Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Well first, you are calling setData, but you have not defined that function. It looks like you called it createData. Second, you've got some naming collision. If you're trying to access your classes property of $prod_data, you should use $this->prod_data['whatever_key']. So try changing the method call to createData, do a var_dump on the array to make sure it actually contains the data you're trying to use, and then change your variable references to $this->prod_data instead of just $prod_data.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I corrected the method name and also how I was accessing the class property but was stil getting an empty array not until I realized I didn't include my database connection script (db.php) and everything is working fine now. Thanks once again.